# Angular 5 custom component CSS

Tags: css, angular

I have a `CSS` file I ONLY want to be loaded when a component is on the page.

I have tried the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testview-testview',
    templateUrl: './templates/testview.html',
    styles: [
        "../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css",
        "../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/theme/black.css"
    ],
})
```

However without any luck. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

**EDIT**

So i am attempting to follow the answer below

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

My Component now looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var Reveal: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'testview-testview',
    templateUrl: './templates/testview.html',
    styleUrls: ['./templates/testview.css'],
})
export class TestviewComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        Reveal.initialize({});
    }

}
```

And my testview.css file looks like this:

```
    @import url("../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css");
@import url("../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/theme/black.css");
```

Comment: Does this also mean you want the CSS to be unloaded when the component is not being displayed anymore?

Comment: @balu preferably

Comment: Take a look at Angular's `ViewEncapsulation` feature. While this won't help you load or unload the CSS at specific times, it will give you precise control over which DOM element / which component the styles are applied to—which, I suppose, is what you actually want(?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to inside the urls inside array of styls: `styleUrls` **instead of** `styles`
**SO**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testview-testview',
    templateUrl: './templates/testview.html',
    styleUrls: [
        "../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css",
        "../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/theme/black.css"
    ],
})
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testview-testview',
    templateUrl: './templates/testview.html',
    styleUrls: ['./templates/testview.css'

    ],
})
```

**in you css `./templates/testview.css` import files**

```
@import url("../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css");
@import url("../../../assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/theme/black.css");
```

Comment: when i do this i get a compiler error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings

Comment: @MarcRasmussen did you change 'styles' to 'styleUrls'? (subtle change)

Comment: The styles get bundled when building. This is technically not a seperate stylesheet anymore getting loaded when the component is created.

Comment: I am updating my question

Comment: try import `/assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css`

Comment: if i do that i get an error: Can't resolve '/assets/vendors/custom/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css'